# Can I prevent a copy constructor with some exception?

Tags: c++, stl, initialization, copy-constructor, shallow-copy

I will use `std::map<int, A>`

`A` is a class and I have to prevent shallow copy,
but there are many classes like `A`, so making a deep copy construct and operator is tiresome.
Since it seems that I don't have to use copy constructor and copy assignment operator,
I decide not to use them.

To prevent some mistakes, I made UnCopyable class, which has private copy constuctor and copy assignment operator, and `A` inherited it.

However, there is one problem. `std::map` use a copy constructor.

I don't want to save `A`'s pointer in the map.

What's the better solution?

Comment: You could store a smart pointer (`std::shared_ptr<A>`) as the value instead of a raw pointer if is the explicit deletion you are concerned about.

Comment: Why is it not copyable? Because someone else has a pointer to it, or just because a proper copy would need to be deep? You might think about implementing "move" semantics in the copy constructor if you know that it will only ever be copied from a temporary.

Comment: I solved this problem by using handle class.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Move semantics in the copy constructor, so like `std::auto_ptr`? That doesn't seem like a good idea (isn't use of `auto_ptr` discouraged for this very reason?).

Comment: @Grizzly If you're only going to copy at initialization, it's not as bad. `std::map` does not perform any reallocation; the only copy required is from the value passed to `insert`. So you could make it like `auto_ptr` except a non-NULL value throws instead of copying. In C++11 of course the problem easily goes away.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I do realize that it would work like that, however I wouldn't feel comfortable writing such code, since that unusual copy behaviour is against the principle of least suprice. Therefore I would expect that sometime in the future someone (might even be me) will forget about that property of the class and try to make an actual copy (or worse try some library function which does that somewhere under the hood) and create a bug which is likely to be hard to track down. Of course I use C++11 so I don't have to consider such a solution anyways.

Comment: @Grizzly Some things you just don't forget are non-copyable, like graph nodes. Between bending the rules a little (a throwing copy constructor *is* a valid way to make a class Copyable), adding indirection to everything (for a large graph, this can be unfeasible), and ditching containers outright, it's the least evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a smart pointer like `std::shared_ptr` or write a proxy class.

E.g.:

```
class Foo {
public:
    std::string name() const;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<Foo> SharedFoo;
```

or

```
class SharedFoo {
public:
    std::string name() const { return instance->name(); }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> instance;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You might think about trying C++11, which has a couple solutions to this kind of problem: `std::map::emplace` which eliminates the Copyable requirement for `A`, and `std::move` which allows you to transfer one object into another without copying.

Also, there is a new, more explicit way to define a class as non-copyable:

```
A( A const & ) = delete;
```

It's a good time to upgrade your C++ compiler.